# What exactly does Apache-Maven's .m2 folder do?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I've researched online, but I could not find a concise answer to .m2 folder's function. I know it serves as a local repository, but I don't know how that how Maven uses that folder.I am running a Maven plugin called SonarQube which scans a project and reports on bad coding practices. However, for SonarQube's Findbugs scanner, it tells me that it cannot locate the binaries for the project. I've searched online and people recommended to purge the .m2 folder since there might be a corrupt jar file in there. The thing is, how does Maven use .m2 when it is building?

Here is a sample of the errors I am getting.

```
WARNING: Could not find class com.alp.altl.capture.capturetool.behavior.coordinate.CaptureDisplay, due to: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/alp/session/display/DisplayComposite
```

Comment: I fear your question has nothing to do with your problem. Could you please post the complete error message?

Comment: Yeah, the error I am getting can be due to many reasons. I posted a sample of the error messages. I got thousands of the same message as above.

Comment: Well what is already in your .m2 folder currently?

Comment: I am not sure as I do not have admin access to that computer. But I would say dependencies Maven has downloaded from our SVN repository.

Comment: From your comment on my answer, I'm now confused - are you saying that you are getting the error in a local build (in Eclipse, perhaps?) but the authoritative build on the server is working correctly? A more complete description of the problem and environment would be helpful.

Comment: I am getting the error when I run mvn:sonar sonar after running mvn clean install. Since I ran with the option -Dsonar.skipPackageDesign=True, Sonar does not fail when it encounters "Class not found" errors. However, when I check Sonar server I have set up (on another computer), all the analysis results are pushed on there. This includes Findbugs, PMD, and Checkstyle results. So I am very confused why SonarQube is complaining it cannot find binaries for my project when Findbugs works.

Comment: If something works in one environment but not another, what's the difference between those environments? Is there a properties file difference? Do the targets run in the same order? Are there file system differences?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am going through the logs one by one. I have a multi-module project. I think I should run "mvn clean package" as there are warnings that state many dependencies could not be resolved. I suspect that this is the root of the problem.

Comment: By the way, I found another person who had the same exact problem as I do. He explained it much clearly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022529/sonar-warnings-due-to-unresolvable-dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like your problem is not having SonarQube configured correctly, nothing to do with the .m2 directory. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven for help configuring your project for analysis.

Comment: Hi, can you possibly give me some hints as to what might be causing this? It says that bytecode scanner cannot find some classes, however I checked those classes on SonarQube server and they are all analyzed.

Comment: We use ant rather than maven, so I don't know maven configuration details. I'm adding a comment to the question, too, as I think you haven't yet fully described the problem.

Comment: I finally managed to solve this issue. Sonar Jenkins plugin apparently does not run the command "mvn clean install". I thought it did. So therefore, I had all of these errors.